# A number smaller than negative infinity in python?

Tags: python, python-2.x

This is possible in python2:

```
None < float('-inf')
```

Also, it *always* returns

```
True
```

However, on python3, this throws

```
TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < int()
```

Why is `None` comparable to integers/floats with python2? Are there any benefits or applications to `None` being orderable in python2?

Comment: Seems to be by design, at least. Not sure why it's useful though: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ab05e7dd2788/Objects/object.c#l778

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I don't think it's a duplicate. None is always smaller than any integer regardless of their reference.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Okay, thanks, that'll do it.

Comment: Everything was comparable in Python 2. Objects of different types were guaranteed to be compared consistently, but the standard made no guarantee. CPython 2 implementation detail:"Objects of different types except numbers are ordered by their type names; objects of the same types that don’t support proper comparison are ordered by their address."

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The dupes are fine but one question of mine they don't answer is how one can take advantage of the orderability of `None` to create succinct code. That was honestly the main purpose of asking this question - to find out how one can apply this. Maybe it's a bit broad.

Comment: The [relevant docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons).

Comment: [For older types, the result of inequality comparison with None isn't defined by the language, and the outcome does vary across CPython releases.](http://bugs.python.org/issue1673405)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Please reopen and post as an answer :p

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all Python 2 allowed comparing all types of mixed types. This wart was [fixed in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons) eventually.

> **CPython implementation detail**: Objects of different types except
>   numbers are ordered by their type names; objects of the same types
>   that don’t support proper comparison are ordered by their address.

For `None` a [quick decision was made by Guido and Tim Peters](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2014-February/132432.html) and it resulted in this [commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/0871e9315ec2395775f600baedacdcbcd4cb5f5c) in Python 2.1(emphasis mine):

> Part of fixing that was removing some cases of "compare objects of
>   different types by comparing the type name strings". Guido & I were
>   both in the office at the time, and one said to the other: "what about
>   `None`? Comparing that to other types via comparing the string `'None'`
>   doesn't make much sense." "Ya, OK ... how about changing `None` to - by
>   default - **comparing 'less than' objects of other types?**" "Don't see
>   why not - sure." "OK, done!
>
> No more than 2 minutes of thought went into it.  There was no intent
>   to cater to any real use case here - the only intent was to pick some
>   arbitrary-but-consistent rule that didn't suck *quite* as badly as
>   pretending None was the string "None" ;-)

Comment: Is the second para of the second quote your text or quoted from the same reference?

Comment: Quoted text: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2014-February/132432.html